# Impossibility to get action approved, trying to "circumvent" policies?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, policy

I'm trying to submit an action for a website I've built. It's a gathering site for tv series fans that can "check in" to episode to let others know they watched it. I'm trying to mirror these checkins on Facebook through Open Graph and I've been struggling to get actions approved for the last two weeks, a frustrating effort to say the least.

First, I used the "watch" verb with a custom action, and that wasn't ok; then, I renamed the action `{name} checked in to {episode}`, and there was a "grammatical issue", which I honestly don't see. Now I used the default "watch" action and the last rejection message beats them all on lack of clarity:

```
Your action conflicts with section I.3 of the Platform Policies
(https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). You must not circumvent (or claim
to circumvent) our intended limitations on core Facebook features and functionality.
```

There are other websites that do exactly the same thing I'm trying to achieve (e.g. http://trakt.tv/), so in no way I can understand how I'm trying to circumvent the policy, which obviously isn't my goal.

How do you suggest I tackle this problem? Do you have any suggestion on how I can get the functionality approved?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use "check in" mostly because its internal Facebook action like "comment, like, and so on". So you need to name that action differently

Comment: But what about the built-in action "watch"? As I said, other services use that, so they must have been approved somehow.

Comment: watch is app specific, one of default fb actions, mostly because you cant create "watch" action directly on FB, but you can create "comment, like, checkin" directly on Facebook, so you need to integrate their plugin or whatsoever to let user create that action on your website

Comment: I actually can create watch actions: the action works with my user and the other developers without any problem, as expected. It's just the approval process that's incredibly opaque.